# Hide textbox when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using jquery to enable 3 fields ('withdrawn', 'email' & 'serial number') when my 'update'  checkbox is checked. It is working but I would prefer if my 'email' & 'serial number' fields were actually hidden until the 'update' checkbox is checked, however I am unsure how to hide them properly & then what jquery code to use to unhide them.  I'd also like the fields to go back to their original state if 'update' is unchecked.  Please help...

```
    <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="checkbox" id="initialNotification">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Intial) Initial notification
        </label>
    </div>    
    <div class="checkbox" id="update" checked ="false">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Update) Update to an existing notification
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.SerialNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.SerialNumber, new { @class= "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.SerialNumber)

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notification.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Notification.Email)

    </div>
</div>

    <div class="checkbox" id="withdrawn">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Notification.Withdrawn, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) The project has been withdrawn
        </label>
    </div>

    @section scripts
{
        <script>         

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Notification_Update").attr("checked", false)
                $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Notification.Update)").trigger("click");             

            });            
            $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Notification.Update)").on("click", function () {                
                if ($(this).is(":checked") || @(Model.Notification.Update.ToString().ToLower()) == true) {
        $(".to-hide").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".to-hide").hide();
    }
            });            
          </script>

    }
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: use `display:none` in css and then `.show()` / `.hide()` in jquery and you also want to do a check for `this.checked` in your change function

Comment: Thanks & sorry, should've mentioned am using MVC5

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Add a class to the container of the elements that would be hidden, e.g.:

   ```
   <div class="form-inline to-hide">
   ```
2. Use this javascript code:

   ```
   $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Notification.Update)").on("click", function() {
       $(".to-hide")[($(this).is(":checked") ? "show" : "hide")]();
   });
   ```

   <sub>*Simplified code below.*</sub>
3. (Optional) Run the event on `document.ready`:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Notification.Update)").trigger("click");
   });
   ```

```js
$("#update").on("click", function() {
    $(".to-hide")[($(this).is(":checked") ? "show" : "hide")]();
}).trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="update" />
<div class="to-hide">Hide me</div>
```

Simplified javascript code(item #2):

```
$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Notification.Update)").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".to-hide").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".to-hide").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I wanted, only when the form first loads, 'Serial Number' and 'Email' are visible.  What would I need to add to make them hidden initially?

Comment: @JohnNewbie the item #3 should do that. It will run the event on the page load, so if the checkbox starts selected or not, the event should do it's work and show/hide the container.

Comment: @JohnNewbie example: if you add `checked="false"` to the checkbox manually, the `trigger("click")` will manage that state.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete novice so I'm a little confused, do I need parts 1, 2 & 3 to make this work?  I am fine up until part 3 but when I try implementing the last part, it all stops working for me

Comment: @JohnNewbie no problem. You need parts 1 and 2. The third is just to open the page with elements hidden in case of the checkbox is not checked and vice versa. Check update.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I think I'm nearly there, the checkbox is operating how I want but I can't get it to come through unchecked when the form first loads.  I have updated my code above, could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @JohnNewbie well, sometimes its kinda tricky dealing with checkboxes in asp.net mvc. Try this: put a `debugger;` in the very first line of your `click` event. Run the page with your dev tools open(F12). It should stop at the debugger. Then run this in the dev tools' Console: `$(this).is(":checked")`. If your checkbox is checked but that statement returns `false`, then you may add a condition in your if: `if ($(this).is(":checked") || @(Model.Notification.Update.ToString().ToLower()) == true)`. It should work.

Comment: I followed your instructions and the statement did return false in the console.  I have tried adding the condition (as shown in edited original code above) but it is doing the same thing....checkbox defaults to checked & hidden fields visible

Comment: @JohnNewbie but your `Model.Notification.Update` is `true` ?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean in your last comment?

Comment: @JohnNewbie I mean, when the page loads, what is the value of `Model.Notification.Update` property? Is it `true`? It is a boolean, right?

Comment: It is a boolean & when I right click my checkbox & inspect element: <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Update field is required." id="Notification_Update" name="Notification.Update" value="true" type="checkbox"><input name="Notification.Update" value="false" type="hidden">

Comment: @JohnNewbie then try this: `if ($(this).is(":checked") || $(this).val() == "true")`

Comment: with this change, the checkbox is still checked by default but no longer hides/shows the fields when you subsequently uncheck/check it